# Not able to select tableview's cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm using Xcode 11.2 and I have a view containing 3 tableviews. They all have outlets to the code and their delegates and datasources are correctly set in the viewDidLoad method.

What happens is that the cell highlights when clicked but then it doesn't remain selected (didSelectRow never gets called).

If I click many times rapidly with the left and right mouse buttons the cell will eventually get selected and the didSelectRow gets called.

Also I noticed that the selection almost always works if I click the cell and at the same time scroll the table a little.

Here some of the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var linesTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstLvlTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLvlTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.linesTableView.dataSource = self
    self.linesTableView.delegate = self
    self.firstLvlTableView.delegate = self
    self.firstLvlTableView.dataSource = self
    self.secondLvlTableView.dataSource = self
    self.secondLvlTableView.delegate = self

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    self.secondLvlTableView.isHidden = true
    self.firstLvlTableView.isHidden = false
    self.linesTableView.isHidden = true
    fetchData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == linesTableView {
        return 0
    } else if tableView == firstLvlTableView {
        return self.salesAssistantLocalized.count //viewModel.typesOfSale.lists.endIndex
    } else if tableView == secondLvlTableView {
        return 4 //viewModel.standardTableLevels.lists.endIndex
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == firstLvlTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstLvlCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.salesAssistantLocalized[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else if tableView == secondLvlTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondLvlCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.levels[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SaleTypeCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    printDebug("Did Select Row \(indexPath.row) for table \(tableView)")
    if tableView == firstLvlTableView {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.secondLvlTableView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be issue in the simulator. Try with real devices.

Comment: Already tried a real device and it does the same.

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Show how you assigned the delegates and datasource.

Comment: It's in the code. In the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Did you put one tableView on top of another one?

Comment: Yes, there's one tableview, then a view on top of that, and then other two tableviews in that view

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what is happening.
All the view controllers are extending from a "BaseViewController" that has a tap gesture recognizer for dismissing the keyboard.
That is causing the problem.

I've simply added a Bool to be able to choose if use it or not:

```
open var useTapGesture: Bool = true
```

and then wrapped the tap gesture code with this:

```
if useTapGesture {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

This way I can use

```
useTapGesture = false
```

in my viewDidLoad method.